# How to use a different router outlet for different routes in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Currently, I am developing a web application with Angular 2.

The base for my application is actually this one: [github.com/ngrx/example-app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app)

The parent container of the layout is this one:
[github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/containers/app.ts](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/containers/app.ts)

In a use case I have, I would like a specific route to lead to a page where the whole layout would not be the same. I need an almost chrome-less page that can be stored later as a screenshot, so the menubar is redundant for this case.

This is the container's template:

```
 <bc-layout>
  <bc-sidenav [open]="showSidenav$ | async">
    <bc-nav-item (activate)="closeSidenav()" routerLink="/" icon="book" hint="View your book collection">
      My Collection
    </bc-nav-item>
    <bc-nav-item (activate)="closeSidenav()" routerLink="/book/find" icon="search" hint="Find your next book!">
      Browse Books
    </bc-nav-item>
  </bc-sidenav>
  <bc-toolbar (openMenu)="openSidenav()">
    Book Collection
  </bc-toolbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</bc-layout>
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to make the app component use a different router outlet for a specific route. First of all, the ActivatedRoute injected in the AppComponent instance is, by [design](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11023), different (that is, empty) from the actual ActivatedRoute that the target component of the route gets access to. This means that in the AppComponent I can't even match the url, because it comes empty.

I also tried to manually set a field to a value with a time delay and then use this field as a condition to switch between two router outlets. The first outlet is inside the layout, while the other is outside (so it would render without the bells and whistles). This didn't work either, because it seems that the router outlet is set only once, when the app component is first loaded, and afterwards no rendering occurs to other router outlets.

To sum it up, I would like something like the following (although an alternative solution might work better):

```
 <bc-layout>
  <bc-sidenav [open]="showSidenav$ | async">
    <bc-nav-item (activate)="closeSidenav()" routerLink="/" icon="book" hint="View your book collection">
      My Collection
    </bc-nav-item>
    <bc-nav-item (activate)="closeSidenav()" routerLink="/book/find" icon="search" hint="Find your next book!">
      Browse Books
    </bc-nav-item>
  </bc-sidenav>
  <bc-toolbar (openMenu)="openSidenav()">
    Book Collection
  </bc-toolbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</bc-layout>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet> <---chromeless outlet
```

Comment: You could use a [named router outlet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterOutlet-directive.html) if you want more than 1 router-outlet in the same component. [Here's](http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/) also a nice article about this.

Comment: The problem with this is that I need it in the root container, the AppComponent, because this is where the layout is defined. This means that I have to define children routes. What would be the parent and what the children routes? Currently I have  { path: 'cube/analytics/:id/:algorithm/embed/:part', canActivate: [ CubeExistsGuard ], component: CubeAnalyticsEmbedPage }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, then you need to define children routes, so you have multiple router-outlets.

Please read here how children routes works.

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/child_routes.html

Comment: Yes, I thought of this as well, but then, what would be the parent and what the child component? This is the current route:   {
    path: 'cube/analytics/:id/:algorithm/embed/:part',
    canActivate: [ CubeExistsGuard ],
    component: CubeAnalyticsEmbedPage
    
  }

Comment: The parent is always that component, where you define the router-outlet. And the childs defined in the routes, will be displayed in that parent router-outlet. If you want more than one router-outlet in one component, you need to use auxilary router-outlets.

Comment: So I refactored my routes. I made them all children of the LayoutComponent (the one containing the menus), except the one that should be chromeless. I also added a router outlet to the LayoutComponent and move all the chrome to the LayoutComponent. Now,  the route that is outside the LayoutComponent children renders using only the router outlet in AppComponent, so it renders chromeless. Thanks!